# Getting a null value when parsing JSON in Swift 2.0 with swiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift2, swifty-json

I'm getting a null value when I try to parse json from a url. What am I missing, or what *should* I be implementing to simply load a json value and put inside of a `UICollectionView`?

This is json I get from the web service. I have validated it with a validation tool and it is correct:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "count": 72,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 818,
            "name": "1. product",
            "price": "155.00"
        },
        {
            "id": 812,
            "name": "2. product",
            "price": "62.00"
        },
       {
            "id": 26,
            "name": "3. product",
            "price": "213.00"
        },
       {
            "id": 657,
            "name": "4. product",
            "price": "21.00"
        },
       {
            "id": 347,
            "name": "5. product",
            "price": "57.00"
        }
```

I need to get the name and price values from the above json.

This is the swiftyJSON code block called in `viewDidLoad`. I suspect the problem is here, but I'm not sure.

```
let json = JSON(data: products)
if let productName = json["data"][0]["name"].string {
    print("Product: \(productName)")
}
```

Comment: What does your code print? Can you show more about where you get `products`? What happens if you print `products` or `json["data"]`?

Comment: It doesn't print anything because the code starting with "print("Product..." never called.

Comment: what type is `products` in your example? can you show a bite more code of how you get the json from network?

Comment: sure, the following is the code snippet in DataManager;

Comment: let productsURL = url

class DataManager {
    
    class func getProductsFromWebservice(success: ((productsData: NSData!) -> Void)) {
        //1
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: productsURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            //2
            if let urlData = data {
                //3
                success(productsData: urlData)
            }
        })
    }

Answer (score 0):

You could simply avoid null fields in JSON by overriding init function in your model class.
Depend of your mapping data of course. If you will get JSON null object, this constructor will simply replace null to default value

For example:

```
override init() {
   mapField1 = "" // string value
   mapField2 = 0 // number value
}
```

About ur code. Where did you take 0 key in your JSON? It's only `json["data.name"]` or `json["data.price"]`

Comment: Yes, I initialised default values on model class. I may be put [0] to wrong place because I guess the json I got from the web service is array of dictionary and i'm not good at it.